# How to insert bash variables in awk?

Tags: bash, command-line, awk

1. How to insert bash variables in awk (for example i need to do in in some for loop - like this: in first iteration use awk to search string by first column, next by second column and so on with using **diffent pattern from bash variables** in awk)

or

2. find the simple way to make **pattern at all (as string)** and recieve it to awk as argument.

---

Trying to insert bash variables in awk -

I have some log -

```
$ cat > log
test1
test2
ahaha
hahah
```

i do

```
$ cat log | awk '$1~/test1|test2/ {print }'
test1
test2
```

all ok

i need to paste bash variables in awk

```
$ a=test1
$ b=test2
```

then i try to insert

```
$ cat log | awk 'BEGIN{a;b} $1~/a|b/ {print }'
ahaha
hahah

$ cat log |  awk -v a=test1 -v b=test2 '$1~/a|b/ {print }'
ahaha
hahah
```

---

How to make all patern as string and recieve it to awk as argument -

```
$ p='$1~/test1|test2/ {print }'

$ cat log | awk p
# get test1
# get test2
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass the patterns as variables to awk and compare explicitly using dynamic patterns (i.e. match against patterns in strings)...

```
awk -v pat="$a|$b" '$1 ~ pat' log
```

or

```
awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" '$1 ~ a "|" b ' log
```

Note: You can't use static patterns /.../ (or only by using dirty quoting/escaping).

Comment: it doesn't work as i want. no search availiable in this example. `$ awk -v pat="$a|$b" '$1 ~ pat' log` - show all strings and `$ awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" '$1 ~ a "|" b ' log` too.

Comment: blackbird, you must have done something wrong. I just confirmed my two proposals with bash and ksh.

Answer (score 4):

Awk does not expand variables inside `/.../`.

But

```
$ cat log |  awk -v a=test1 -v b=test2 '$1 ~ a || $1 ~ b {print }'
```

and

```
$ p='$1~/test1|test2/ {print }'
$ cat log |  awk "$p"
```

should work (untested)